# javascript: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when I store html in var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get the error animations.js:121 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.
I want to store some html in a var. in some vars above it works but in this one not. here is one that WORKS:

```
  var informatikertext = "<p>Als Informatiker/Informatikerin EFZ entwickelst, realisierst, integrierst, testest und unterhält du Informatiklösungen. Mit dem Schwerpunkt Betriebsinformatik bist du Fachperson für den Aufbau und die Wartung von Informatiksys- temen. Du installierst Computer, Server und Netzwerke, erweiterst Gerätekon gurationen und Software-Installationen. Du unterstützt die Mitarbeitenden aller Abteilungen im ICT-Be- reich. Das macht deine Ausbildung abwechs- lungsreich und interessant. </p><h2 class='job-undertitle'>DAS IST UNS WICHTIG</h2><ul><li>Interesse an Mathematik</li><li>Interesse am Lösen komplexer Aufgaben-stellungen</li><li>Logisch-abstraktes Denkvermögen</li>\
    <li>Dienstleistungsbereitschaft</li>\
  </ul>\
<h2 class='job-undertitle'>DAS BRINGST DU MIT</h2>\
<ul>\
  <li>Abgeschlossene höchste Volksschulstufe</li>\
  <li>Gute Leistungen in Mathematik und\
Naturwissenschaften</li>\
</ul>\
<h2 class='job-undertitle'>SO LÄUFT DIE AUSBILDUNG</h2>\
<ul>\
  <li>4-jährige Ausbildung und Abschluss mit eidgenössischem Fähigkeitszeugnis (EFZ)</li>\
  <li>Integrierte Berufsmatura möglich</li>\
</ul>  \
";
```

and this does NOT WORK:

```
      var hoteltext = "<p> Als Hotelfachfrau /-fachmann EFZ organisierst und erledigst du vielseitige Arbeiten. Du bist in den Bereichen Verp egung, Service, Reinigung, Wäscheversorgung und Blumenp ege tätig. Die Ausbildung im Spital bringt dich mit vielen verschiedenen Menschen in Kontakt. Deine Arbeiten koordinierst du mit den Tätigkeiten des P egepersonals. Auch im administrativen Bereich leistest du dank Kenntnissen in der PC-Anwendung quali zierte Mitarbeit. </p>\
  <h2 class='job-undertitle'>DAS IST UNS WICHTIG</h2>\
  <ul>\
    <li>Ruhe und Übersicht bewahren in hektischen Situationen</li>\
    <li>Organisationstalent</li>\
    <li>Ordnungssinn und Hygienebewusstsein</li>\
    <li>Belastbarkeit und Flexibilität</li>\
  </ul>\
  <h2 class='job-undertitle'>DAS BRINGST DU MIT</h2>\
  <ul>\
    <li>Abgeschlossene obligatorische Schulzeit</li>\
    <li>Gute Deutschkenntnisse</li>\
  </ul>\
  <h2 class='job-undertitle'>SO LÄUFT DIE AUSBILDUNG</h2>\
  <ul>\
    <li>3-jährige Ausbildung und Abschluss mit eidgenössischem Fähigkeitszeugnis (EFZ)</li>\
    <li>Integrierte Berufsmatura möglich</li>\
    <li>Während allen drei Ausbildungsjahren zwei fünfwöchige Blockkurse in einem Schulhotel von hotelleriesuisse</li>\
  </ul>\

  ";
```

Maybe it is a problem that I copied the text out of a pdf?

Comment: You're missing a backslash on the last line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing to escape the blank line:

```
 </ul>\
\
";
```

Comment: Note that if the blank line is not desired, you need to just remove the escape character from the end of the `</ul>`

Answer (score 1):

You have an additional space added in the variable before the end double quote on your variable value assignment. Please try removing the space.